# How to hand 2D vector created from file to class constructor?

Tags: c++, class, c++11, file-io

I'm trying to pass a 2D vector from main to a class' constructor. The vector is created and instantiated from main, but needs to be used in the class.

I've tried replicating the issue with a small bit of code which hasn't been successful:

```
class ExampleClass {

public:
    ExampleClass(vector<string> fileVector) {
        vector<string> classVector;
        classVector = fileVector;
    }

    void printVector() {
        cout << "classVector[1][1]" << classVector[1][1] << endl;
    }
};



int main()
{
string fileName;
ifstream inputFile;

cout << "Enter file name: " << endl;
cin >> fileName;


inputFile.open("filename");
vector<string> fileVector{ istream_iterator<string>(inputFile), 
istream_iterator<string>() };



    ExampleClass example(fileVector);
    example.printVector;
    inputFile.close();
}
```

I'd expect the `fileVector` from `main` to be accessible in `ExampleClass`, where it is copied to `classVector`. Instead, `classVector` throws an error:

"identifier "classVector" is undefined"

Comment: Don't use `vector<string> vector;`. Aside from that, your code contains basic errors regarding the definition of classes. It will be good for you in the long run to learn the fundamentals of the language from [a good textbook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Forgot to change the name for the example. Care to expand on the basic errors?

Comment: You are trying to read from a file named `"filename"`, rather than a file whose name is stored in the variable `fileName`

Comment: `classVector` is a local variable in `ExampleClass` constructor. It's destroyed when the constructor returns; assigning to it is rather pointless. Anyway, in `printVector` the name `classVector` is not declared; you likely get a compiler error to this effect.

Comment: `example.printVector` is not a valid C++ syntax. You likely get another error to this effect.

Comment: For your line of code: `example.printVector;` you are not invoking the function because you are missing `()` after the function name. To fix this one line of code change it to `example.printVector();` to actually call the class's member function. This is only one of your errors that sticks out at first glance. The other was already mentioned when you passed `"filename"` to your ifstream's open function. I think  you meant `inputFile.open(fileName);` There still may be other errors...